# Converting Delta table into JSON in Azure Data Factory or Azure Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, azure-cognitive-search, delta-lake

I have tables with over 50 million records in each hence, stored in delta format instead of CSV and are stored in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. I want to convert them into JSON format in Azure Data Factory or Azure Logic Apps so that I could pull them into Azure Cognitive Search Services to later integrate it with Azure OpenAI for answers generated with the contextual knowledge specific to my organization.

I dont know how to achieve it and neither could i find the resources or examples of people doing it. I am not even sure if it's possible

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far? error/blockers? sample input and expected output?

Comment: nothing
I don't even know if it can be done

Answer (score 0):

Use the **copy activity in ADF** to copy the data from delta table to data lake Json here copy activity sink won't support Json file so first copy to a csv file later use another copy activity to convert this csv file into a Json file. Refer the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-databricks-delta-lake?tabs=data-factory) for step-by-step procedure.

You can also try databricks as another workaround follow the below steps:

**Step 1:**
Read the delta table as a spark data frame in the data bricks notebook.

`df=spark.sql("select * from <delta table name>")`

**Step 2:**
Create a mount point to the data lake gen2

```
dbutils.fs.mount(source = "wasbs://<container name>@<storage acc name>.blob.core.windows.net",
                 mount_point = "/mnt/<mount_point>",
                 extra_configs = {'fs.azure.account.key.<storage acc name>.blob.core.windows.net': '<access key>'}
)
```

**Step 3:**
Write the data frame into a Json using the above mount point

`df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").json('/mnt/<mount point>/myjson.json')`

[image]

Your delta table data will be copied to Json like below sample:

[image]